# Are devas more glorious and greater than human comprehension?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, gods

Are there any verses in any scriptures that state that the devas are beyond human comprehension? And that their will and nature are not knowable to humans?

Comment: what do you mean by glory and greatness?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Their power, their nature.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda In any case, is it true that the nature of the devas is beyond human comprehension?

Comment: your comprehension is provided by Devas..I mean what you consciously realize internally is facilitated & filtered by Devas...So it's analyzing what they do inside you...Sama Veda Agneya Kanda etc. are all about the greatness of Indra Gladdening our senses etc. So, they & their greatness( by their virtuous actions)  are also comprehensible..

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman If our comprehension is provided by devas, then that means that they themselves should be incomprehensible.

Comment: Not necessarily. You are looking at it as an outside observer in the spirit of scientific inquiry..How did the doctors know what is a disease when they themselves don't have that? So, by analyzing and concluding about our physical bodies scientifically we were able to learn so much...Similarly, by looking at the comprehension aspect that the devas work on...you will be able to learn & comprehend many aspects of it...Not all of it though : -) !